# AutoHotkey - XButton1 Not Working With Control

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

I'm playing a game that requires you to hold down the control button to jump. What I wanna do is make it so that the XButton1 (Mouse Button 4) holds down the Control, then when I release XButton1, Control also releases.

It's odd because the XButton2 (Mouse Button 5) works, but XButton1 doesn't. The XButton1 is the 'back' button on my mouse, and that function works.

If I use this code: XButton:: Send {Lctrl Down}, that works, but the Control doesn't release until I click the Left Control again.

Does anyone know what I can do to make this work?

-Edit-

I just tried the following code: XButton1::Soundbeep and it worked, which is weird. But assigning the Control to it doesn't, but assigning it to XButton2 does.

Answer (score 0):

Especially for modifier keys, you need to address both `Up` and `Down` as follows:

```
XButton1::Send {LCtrl Down}
XButton1 Up::Send {LCtrl Up}
```

**Edit**:
If the above doesn't work on that particular game, try:

```
XButton1::SendInput {LCtrl Down}
XButton1 Up::SendInput {LCtrl Up}
```

or

```
XButton1::SendPlay {LCtrl Down}
XButton1 Up::SendPlay {LCtrl Up}
```

Comment: It's weird because if I add the first line: XButton1::Send {LCtrl Down} it works but I have to manually click Left Control to make it stop, but if I add both lines, it doesn't work at all. What could the problem be?

Comment: I tried the other 2 and it still doesn't work. It's actually weird. Like I said, the Xbutton1: Send {LCtrl Down} works but if I add the 2nd line, it doesn't work at all. However, The codes work for the mouse 5 button. Do you know what the issue could be?

Comment: You mean `XButton2` works but `XButton1` doesn't? If so, an app must be doing something with the input before AutoHotkey could, such as a custom app/driver made by the particular manufacturer of your mouse. Try uninstalling/disabling it or using a generic mouse driver.

Comment: XButton1 (Which is the 'back' button) works like it's supposed to. XButton2 (Which is the 'forward' button) also works like it's supposed to. XButton1 only doesn't work when I assign the "LCtrl Down" to it, however if I assign it to XButton2, it works.